# What's the difference between FQDNs and Hostnames

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, hostname, dns-zone, fqdn

First of all, I wanna say that I know how DNS Servers work and also I know about the records in a DNS Zone File!

I'm not an expert but I have some knowledge about them. I'm confused! why?! because I don't know what's the exact difference between hostnames and FQDNs.

I know that some thing like my.example.com. is a FQDN. somebody told me it's a FQDN because of the existance of "dot" at the end of it.

I think the final dot at the end of it reffers to the root dns servers in the world, right?

Is my.example.com a hostname? (note that it's doesn't have any final dots!)

maybe "my" is the hostname?!

Actually i'm confused!

What's the difference between a hostname and a FQDN, guys?!

Sorry, My english isn't very good. excuse me if I made a mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A host name is part of a FQDN. For example, in `www.example.com`, the `www` is the host name, and `example.com` is the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I am pasting the answer for your knoledge. This has been already answered at serverfault.

---

Your hostname is the name of your computer.

Your fully qualified domain name is your hostname plus the domain your company uses often ending in .local.

So if the name of your computer is bob, and your company's domain is contoso.local, your computer's fully qualified domain name is bob.contoso.local

Hostname: bob

Domain: contoso.com

FQDN: bob.contoso.com

In the case of a domain like contoso.local I did not use an "external" internet domain name. This name doesn't have to be the only way that you address the server. If you make it available by its IP address you can use DNS or that IP address to allow external users to access it.

LINK:  [What is the difference between a hostname and a fully qualified domain name?](https://serverfault.com/questions/269838/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hostname-and-a-fully-qualified-domain-name)

---

Try to find answers yourself first instead of raising a question.