# Setting the hostname: FQDN or short name?

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, hostname

I've noticed that the "preferred" method of setting the system hostname is fundamentally different between Red Hat/CentOS and Debian/Ubuntu systems.

[CentOS documentation](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-sysconfig-network.html) and the [RHEL deployment guide](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-sysconfig.html#s2-sysconfig-network) say the hostname *should be the FQDN*:

> `HOSTNAME=<value>`, where `<value>` should be the Fully Qualified Domain
> Name (FQDN), such as `hostname.example.com`, but can be whatever
> hostname is necessary.

The [RHEL install guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/installation_guide/sn-netconfig-x86) is slightly more ambiguous:

> Setup prompts you to supply a host name for this computer, either as a
> *fully-qualified domain name* (FQDN) in the format *hostname.domainname*
> or as a short host name in the format *hostname*.

[The Debian reference](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch03.en.html#_the_hostname) says the hostname *should not use the FQDN*:

> 3.5.5. The hostname
>
> The kernel maintains the system **hostname**. The init script in runlevel
> S which is symlinked to "**/etc/init.d/hostname.sh**" sets the system
> hostname at boot time (using the **hostname** command) to the name stored
> in "**/etc/hostname**". This file should contain **only** the system hostname,
> not a fully qualified domain name.

I haven't seen any specific recommendations from IBM about which to use, but [some software](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.tsam.doc_7.1%2Fc_prep_ms_for_aix.html) seems to have a preference.

My questions:

- In a heterogeneous environment, is it better to use the vendor recommendation, or choose one and be consistent across all hosts?
- What software have you encountered which is sensitive to whether the hostname is set to the FQDN or short name?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I would choose a consistent approach across the entire environment. Both solutions work fine and will remain compatible with most applications. There is a difference in manageability, though.

I go with the short name as the HOSTNAME setting, and set the FQDN as the first column in `/etc/hosts` for the server's IP, followed by the short name.

I have not encountered many software packages that enforce or display a preference between the two. I find the short name to be cleaner for some applications, specifically logging. Maybe I've been unlucky in seeing internal domains like `server.northside.chicago.rizzomanufacturing.com`. Who wants to see that in the logs or a *shell prompt*?

Sometimes, I'm involved in company acquisitions or restructuring where internal domains and/or subdomains change. I like using the short hostname in these cases because logging, kickstarts, printing, systems monitoring, etc. do not need full reconfiguration to account for the new domain names.

A typical RHEL/CentOS server setup for a server named "rizzo" with internal domain "ifp.com", would look like:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network:
HOSTNAME=rizzo
...
```

-

```
/etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

172.16.100.13   rizzo.ifp.com rizzo
```

-

```
[root@rizzo ~]# hostname 
rizzo
```

-

```
/var/log/messages snippet:
Dec 15 10:10:13 rizzo proftpd[19675]: 172.16.100.13 (::ffff:206.15.236.182[::ffff:206.15.236.182]) - Preparing to               
 chroot to directory '/app/upload/GREEK'
Dec 15 10:10:51 rizzo proftpd[20660]: 172.16.100.13 (::ffff:12.28.170.2[::ffff:12.28.170.2]) - FTP session opened.
Dec 15 10:10:51 rizzo proftpd[20660]: 172.16.100.13 (::ffff:12.28.170.2[::ffff:12.28.170.2]) - Preparing to chroot                
to directory '/app/upload/ftp/SRRID'
```

Comment: Like you, I prefer the short name, however I discovered recently that some Oracle applications require the output of `hostname` to be the FQDN. Just having it in `/etc/hosts` isn't good enough. That messed with my consistency.

Comment: The difference in capitalization of the hostnames in this example is surely not a best practice
ref: http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc1178

Comment: Shouldn't `/etc/sysconfig/network` contain lines like: `NETWORKING=yes`, `NETWORKING_IPV6=no`, `HOSTNAME=example.com`, `NISDOMAIN=example` ?

Comment: @JasmineLognnes Right, I've corrected it. I hope ewwhite doesn't mind.

Comment: It's not just about preference. See [`hostname(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname) on any Linux machine.

Comment: The only relevant example of Red Hat-related software I happen to have encountered that actually has a hard requirement for FQDNs in `hostname` is [IPA](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Identity_Management_Guide/#hostname-requirements), that is, [FreeIPA](http://www.freeipa.org/page/Quick_Start_Guide#DNS_Rules).

Comment: @user158140 My Ubuntu 20.04 hostname manpage says:

       */etc/hostname  Historically  this file was supposed to only contain the
       hostname and not the full canonical FQDN.  Nowadays  most  software  is
       able  to  cope with a full FQDN here. This file is read at boot time by
       the system initialization scripts to set the hostname.*

So it doesn't tell you what to set it to.

Answer (score 47):

Pretty much all software is sensitive to correctly setting the hostname. While I was working at Digg I once brought the entire site down for 2 hours due to making a seemingly innocent change in `/etc/hosts` that affected the system's notion of hostname. Tread lightly. That said, you may be slightly confused here. I don't think the `HOSTNAME=` setting is directly equivalent to how Debian-based distributions use `/etc/hostname`.

What works for me in a heterogeneous environment is:

1. Set the hostname in the vendor-recommended manner, using a conditional in your config management software.
2. Use the `hostname` command to set the hostname used by the kernel, etc.
3. In `/etc/hosts`:

   ```
   127.0.0.1    localhost
   10.0.0.1     hostname.example.com     hostname
   ```

This configuration has not failed me yet.

Comment: This is pretty much the setup I use at work.  The shortname should be fine as long as the domain name is in the DNA search path (/etc/resolv.conf) for the relevant machines in your environment

Comment: do you specifically recommend a local network IP as opposed to a public one?

Comment: not really recommended for notebook configuration as it is probably changing network it is connected to

Answer (score 41):

You will certainly have no problem finding references online which will tell you to definitely do it one way or another.  It seems to me however that having a short name as the hostname, and have the fully qualified name in /etc/hosts is certainly much more prevalent.  It seems like the more sensible way, as then services which need a fully qualified name can be adapted to call `hostname --fqdn` instead.

I've only come across one piece of software recently which rigidly requires a fqdn to be returned by `hostname`, which was ganeti.  They document this [here](http://docs.ganeti.org/ganeti/2.3/html/install.html#hostname-issues).  I don't see any reason they cannot adapt to `hostname --fqdn`, however.

Comment: "I don't see any reason they cannot adapt to `hostname --fqdn`" is answered in the first paragraph under "Why a fully qualified host name" -- it requires guesswork, and requires a working resolver.  Asking the kernel is the safest and most reliable option.

Comment: @womble - As long as the /etc/hosts file has an entry for the machine (`10.0.0.1  hostname.example.com  hostname`) and /etc/nsswitch.conf specifies local resolution before DNS (`hosts:  files dns`)  then having a working resolver is fulfilled by the local hosts file.  As such that argument for using an FQDN instead of a hostname rarely holds water.  Also, another example of software that rigidly requires `hostname` to return an FQDN is the Zimbra mail server package.

Comment: @crashmaxed: That's several extra requirements, any of which might not be possible in a given environment or screwed up by mistake.  Having the FQDN in the kernel data structures is much simpler.

Answer (score 17):

Somewhat tangentially, while researching this question, I have been going crazy enough to check the source code of "hostname" and write a script to print investigative results (Fedora 19). What is missing is a look at "/etc/hosts", which in my humble opinion should be kept the hell out of all of this in the first place.

```
#!/bin/bash

function pad {
   if [[ $1 == '?' ]]; then
      printf "%-23s" "?"
   else
      printf "%-23s" "'$1'"
   fi
}

# ----- Kernel -----

# Two ways to configure the kernel values: 
# 1) Put FQDN into "kernel.hostname" and nothing into "kernel.domainname"
# 2) Put machine name into "kernel.hostname" and DNS domain name into "kernel.domainname" (makes more sense)

echo "== Kernel values =="
echo

H=`/sbin/sysctl -n kernel.hostname`
D=`/sbin/sysctl -n kernel.domainname`

echo "Kernel hostname: '$H'"
echo "Kernel domainname: '$D'"

# ----- What does bash say -----

echo
echo "== According to bash =="
echo

echo "HOSTNAME = '$HOSTNAME'"

# ----- Hostname config file ------

echo
echo "== Hostname config file =="
echo

ETCH="/etc/hostname"

if [[ -f $ETCH ]]; then
   CONTENTS=`cat $ETCH`
   echo "File '$ETCH' contains: '$CONTENTS'"
else
   echo "File '$ETCH' does not exist"
fi

# ----- Network config file ------

echo
echo "== Network config file =="
echo

SYSN="/etc/sysconfig/network"

if [[ -f $SYSN ]]; then
   LINE=`grep -e "^HOSTNAME=" $SYSN`
   if [[ -n $LINE ]]; then
      echo "File '$SYSN' contains: '$LINE'"
   else 
      echo "File '$SYSN' exists but does not contain a line for 'HOSTNAME'"
   fi
else
   echo "File '$SYSN' does not exist"
fi

# ----- Nodename -------

echo
echo "== Nodename =="
echo

UNAME=`uname --nodename` # On Linux, this is the hostname

echo "The 'nodename' given by 'uname --nodename' is: '$UNAME'"

# ----- The 'hostname' mess ------

THE_HOSTNAME=`hostname`
SHORT_NAME=`hostname --short`
NIS_DNAME=`domainname`     
YP_DNAME=`hostname --yp`    # Same as `nisdomainname` ; this may fail with "hostname: Local domain name not set"

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
   YP_DNAME="?"
fi

echo
echo "== 'hostname' directly obtained values =="
echo
echo "The result of gethostname();"
echo "...obtained by running 'hostname'"
echo "Hostname: $(pad $THE_HOSTNAME)"
echo
echo "The part before the first '.' of the value returned by gethostname();"
echo "...obtained by running 'hostname --short'"
echo "Short name: $(pad $SHORT_NAME)"
echo
echo "The result of getdomainname(); the code of 'hostname' seems to call this the 'NIS domain name';"
echo "...on Linux, this is the kernel-configured domainname;"
echo "...obtained by running 'domainname'"
echo "NIS domain name: $(pad $NIS_DNAME)"
echo
echo "The result of yp_get_default_domain(), which may fail;"
echo "...obtained by running 'ĥostname --yp'"
echo "YP default domain: $(pad $YP_DNAME)"

DNS_DNAME=`hostname --domain`  # Same as `dnsdomainname`'
FQDN_NAME=`hostname --fqdn`
ALIAS_NAME=`hostname --alias`

echo
echo "== 'hostname' values obtained via DNS =="
echo
echo "The part after the first '.' of the 'canonical name' value returned by getaddrinfo(gethostname());"
echo "...obtained by running 'hostname --domain'"
echo "DNS domain name: $(pad $DNS_DNAME)"
echo
echo "The 'canonical name' value returned by getaddrinfo(gethostname());"
echo "...obtained by running 'hostname --fqdn'"
echo "Fully qualified hostname: $(pad $FQDN_NAME)"
echo
echo "Alias obtained by gethostbyname(gethostname());"
echo "...obtained by running 'hostname --alias'"
echo "Hostname alias: $(pad $ALIAS_NAME)"

BY_IP_ADDR=`hostname --ip-address`
ALL_IP_ADDR=`hostname --all-ip-addresses`
ALL_FQDN_NAMES=`hostname --all-fqdn`

echo
echo "== 'hostname' values obtained by collecting configured network addresses =="
echo
echo "Collect the IP addresses from getaddrinfo(gethostname()), apply getnameinfo(ip) to all those addresses;"
echo "...obtained by running 'hostname --ip-address'"
echo "By IP address: $BY_IP_ADDR"
echo
echo "Call getnameinfo(NI_NUMERICHOST) on all addresses snarfed from active interfaces;"
echo "...obtained by running 'hostname --all-ip-addresses'"
echo "All IP addresses: $ALL_IP_ADDR"
echo
echo "Call getnameinfo(NI_NAMEREQD) on all addresses snarfed from active interfaces (involves lookup in /etc/hosts);"
echo "...obtained by running 'hostname --all-fqdn'"
echo "All fully qualified hostnames: $ALL_FQDN_NAMES"
```

**The output on an Amazon EC2 VM running Fedora 19**, after manually setting the kernel values and filling `/etc/hostname`, but with no changes to `/etc/hosts` might then be like this:

```
== Kernel values ==

Kernel hostname: 'kyubee'
Kernel domainname: 'homelinux.org'

== According to bash ==

HOSTNAME = 'ip-172-31-24-249.localdomain'

== Hostname config file ==

File '/etc/hostname' contains: 'kyubee.homelinux.org'

== Network config file ==

File '/etc/sysconfig/network' exists but does not contain a line for 'HOSTNAME'

== Nodename ==

The 'nodename' given by 'uname --nodename' is: 'kyubee'

== 'hostname' directly obtained values ==

The result of gethostname();
...obtained by running 'hostname'
Hostname: 'kyubee'

The part before the first '.' of the value returned by gethostname();
...obtained by running 'hostname --short'
Short name: 'kyubee'

The result of getdomainname(); the code of 'hostname' seems to call this the 'NIS domain name';
...on Linux, this is the kernel-configured domainname;
...obtained by running 'domainname'
NIS domain name: 'homelinux.org'

The result of yp_get_default_domain(), which may fail;
...obtained by running 'ĥostname --yp'
YP default domain: 'homelinux.org'

== 'hostname' values obtained via DNS ==

The part after the first '.' of the 'canonical name' value returned by getaddrinfo(gethostname());
...obtained by running 'hostname --domain'
DNS domain name: ''

The 'canonical name' value returned by getaddrinfo(gethostname());
...obtained by running 'hostname --fqdn'
Fully qualified hostname: 'kyubee'

Alias obtained by gethostbyname(gethostname());
...obtained by running 'hostname --alias'
Hostname alias: ''

== 'hostname' values obtained by collecting configured network addresses ==

Collect the IP addresses from getaddrinfo(gethostname()), apply getnameinfo(ip) to all those addresses;
...obtained by running 'hostname --ip-address'
By IP address: fe80::8f6:8eff:fe49:9e21%eth0 172.31.24.249

Call getnameinfo(NI_NUMERICHOST) on all addresses snarfed from active interfaces;
...obtained by running 'hostname --all-ip-addresses'
All IP addresses: 172.31.24.249

Call getnameinfo(NI_NAMEREQD) on all addresses snarfed from active interfaces (involves lookup in /etc/hosts);
...obtained by running 'hostname --all-fqdn'
All fully qualified hostnames: ip-172-31-24-249.eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

The resilient way to get the fully qualified hostname in perl would then be:

```
sub getHostname {

   my $hostname_short = `/bin/hostname --short`;
   if ($? != 0) { print STDERR "Could not execute 'hostname --short' -- exiting\n"; exit 1 }
   chomp $hostname_short;

   my $hostname_long  = `/bin/hostname`;
   if ($? != 0) { print STDERR "Could not execute 'hostname' -- exiting\n"; exit 1 }
   chomp $hostname_long;

   if ($hostname_long =~ /^${hostname_short}\..+$/) {
      # "hostname_long" is a qualified version of "hostname_short"
      return $hostname_long
   }
   else {
      # both hostnames are "short" (and are equal)
      die unless ($hostname_long eq $hostname_short);

      my $domainname = `/bin/domainname`;
      if ($? != 0) { print STDERR "Could not execute 'domainname' -- exiting\n"; exit 1 }
      chomp $domainname;

      if ($domainname eq "(none)") {
         # Change according to taste
         return "${hostname_short}.localdomain"
      }
      else {
         return "${hostname_short}.${domainname}"
      }
   }
}
```

and in bash it would be:

```
function getHostname {

   local hostname_short=`/bin/hostname --short`

   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "Could not execute 'hostname --short' -- exiting" >&2; exit 1
   fi

   local hostname_long=`/bin/hostname`

   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "Could not execute 'hostname' -- exiting" >&2; exit 1
   fi

   if [[ $hostname_long =~ ^"$hostname_short"\..+$ ]]; then
      # "hostname_long" is a qualified version of "hostname_short"
      echo $hostname_long
   else
      # both hostnames are "short" (and are equal)
      if [[ $hostname_long != $hostname_short ]]; then
         echo "Cannot happen: '$hostname_long' <> '$hostname_short' -- exiting" >&2; exit 1
      fi

      local domainname=`/bin/domainname`

      if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
         echo "Could not execute 'domainname' -- exiting" >&2; exit 1
      fi

      if [[ domainname == '(none)' ]]; then
         # Change according to taste
         echo "${hostname_short}.localdomain"
      else
         echo "${hostname_short}.${domainname}"
      fi
   fi
}
```

**Notes**

Note 1: HOSTNAME is a shell variable that bash provides ("Automatically set to the name of the current host.") but there is no indication about bash arrives at that value.

Note 2: Never forget /etc/hostname in /boot/initrams-FOO.img ...

Comment: Sorry if this should be obvious, but what does any of this have to do with setting the hostname?

Comment: Basically notes I made while researching setting the hostname on my Fedora 19 EC2 instances. As for the result: 1) Set the FQHN in /etc/hostname 2) Do not touch /etc/hosts 3) You may set the 'kernel hostname' either to the FQHN or the unqualified hostname, if unset the value is taken from /etc/hostname 4) You may set the 'kernel domainname' to the domainname, which is nicer than just '(none)'.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** I generally use the FQDN as the hostname (as recommended on RH6/7 docs). However, the more righteous approach would be to use a single-label name as the hostname, setting the FQDN via `/etc/hosts`. So, pick an approach and stick with it whenever possible.

**Long answer:** The main advantage of using the FQDN as the hostname is that the machine name intrinsically embeds domain information. This is very useful when receiving email alert and/or logs for multiple customers/domains, as it avoid duplicate hostnames (ie: hostnames are more-or-less guaranteed to be unique across multiple sites/customers/domains). For example, SNMP `sysName` show the hostname by default and, by using the FQDN, it simply conveys a more useful information. The same is true for `zabbix-agent` (and other monitor tools) or for bash `$HOSTNAME`. While you can configure such tools for using FQDNs even on machine with single-label hostname, or configure them in an hierarchical model which clearly shows the domain containing the machine, this is additional work.

Some applications even *require* using a FQDN as the hostname, but they are quite the exception. Still, when the exception hits, the homogeneous use of single-label hostname is lost. This probably is the main reason behind RedHat's recommendation to use a FQDN as the hostname on RH6/7. More recent docs are more vague. On ["Performing a standard RHEL 8 installation"](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/performing_a_standard_rhel_8_installation/index) one can read:

> The host name can be either a fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) in
> the format hostname.domainname, or a short host name with no domain
> name. Many networks have a Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP)
> service that automatically supplies connected systems with a domain
> name. To allow the DHCP service to assign the domain name to this
> machine, specify only the short host name

while ["Performing an advanced RHEL 8 installation"](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/performing_an_advanced_rhel_8_installation/index) states:

> If your network does not provide a DHCP service, always use the FQDN
> as the system’s host name

In the years between the original question, user applications have learned to treat FQDN hostnames without the issue described in the previous answers. For example, bash `PS1` prompt uses `\h` (the hostname up to the first '.') by default, and `rsyslog` does *not* preserve FQDN in logfiles by default. In other words, the usability drawback of a FQDN hostname are no more for many common tools. For these reasons, I generally set the system hostname as a FQDN, leaving the shortname on `/etc/hosts` as required.

The reason to **not** use a FQDN hostname is that, frankly, this is *The Right Thing To Do*. As respectively stated in the [debian docs](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch03.en.html#_the_hostname) and [hostname man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hostname.5.html):

> This file should contain only the system hostname, not a fully
> qualified domain name

and

> It is recommended that this name contains only a single label, i.e.
> without any dots

So, while I do *feel* uneasy to use a FQDN hostname, it *is* easier using it in my environments.

Please note this is not an appeal against single-label hostname. If they work for you, continue using it. Otherwise, give the FQDN hostname a try.

Answer (score -4):

The /etc/hosts options works well.

But you want to make sure that all the proper files are updated run the **setup** tool

Comment: My distribution doesn't have a "setup" tool; which distribution are you using that has one?

Comment: any redhat based OS has the setup tool rhel/centos/fedora whar OS are you using?

Comment: Since the question talks about differences between RHEL-based and Debian-based distros, we must assume the asker uses both. There is no 'setup' tool on Debian-based distros.

Answer (score -4):

Hm... In the linux hosts, if you want change HOSTNAME and FQDN, you should solved 3 steps (for example, new host is **rizzo.ifp.com**):

**Step #1** Change HOST value in the NETWORK properties config:

```
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Change or add string:

```
HOSTNAME=rizzo.ifp.com
```

**Step #2** Edit your hosts config

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
#IPv4
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
[External IP]   rizzo rizzo.ifp.com
```

**Step #3** Reboot your host
Well done, just check new configuration

```
[rizzo@rizzo]# hostname -f
rizzo.ifp.com
```

Answer (score -4):

The order is not right. It has to be:

```
1.2.3.4 full.example.com full
```

So the example could like this:

```
[External IP] rizzo.example.com rizzo
```

Comment: This question has already really quality answers. This does not add anything new.