# Configuring Apache on CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I've just deployed a new CentOS 5.7 box with a base install. After the base install I ran

```
yum install httpd
```

and confirmed that Apache was installed.

I created a test index.html file in /var/www/html/ and then restarted apache expecting that when I connect to the server in a browser that the test page would be displayed.

However, when I connect, all I see is:

ERROR
Service Unavailable

---

The requested service is unavailable.

Please try again later.

I'm sure there is something very simple that I'm missing here but I don't have a lot of linux experience so I'm hoping somebody can lend a hand.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you verified that apache is actually running?  "ps auxw |grep http".  Also, "netstat -pntl |grep 80" should slow your httpd process LISTENing on port 80.

Comment: When I ran the netstat command it came up blank so it would appear that apache is not running as you suggested may be possible. I will google how to start it up...thanks.

Comment: I ran "apachectl start" and it said command not found so I ran "/usr/sbin/apachectl start" and then ran your netstat command and it now says "tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      7847/httpd" However, when I try to connect to the site it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default CentOS has a firewall enabled. You need to open port 80 in your firewall to allow access to the apache server.

```
sudo iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

If this works then

```
sudo service iptables save
```

to save the working configuration for the next restart.

Comment: This answer would have worked as well but unfortunately I already awarded it...I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: When I try to input the rule I run into an error...something simple likely again but since it is a different question I will ask another question for it, thanks.

Comment: error message ?

Comment: It was resolved here: http://serverfault.com/questions/360914/unable-to-create-rule-in-iptables-to-open-port-80

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
Service iptables stop
service httpd restart
```

**NOTE:** the reason is that by default CentOS installation has the Firewall On, then what we did here is to disable it, but when you restart then activates again with this command: "`chkconfig iptables off`" we disable it permanently.

but you can also add a rule to allow port rute 80 if you want

Comment: This was the answer I needed. Can you explain why this worked and then I'll award you the check? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The first command will turn off the firewall.  So, it looks like the firewall was running.

Comment: Thanks for this blackridersws. I'm going to look up how to add that rule to allow port 80 now. I knew this must have been something simple and it was...I appreciate your help.

Comment: Telling people to disable their firewall when there is an equally easy and better solution really is a bad idea.

Comment: Agreed, I've changed the accepted answer to yours, thank you.

Comment: +1 better than mucking about with iptables. thx.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you have a [valid hosts entry](https://serverfault.com/questions/331936/setting-the-hostname-fqdn-or-short-name/331942#331942) in `/etc/hosts`. Apache won't start successfully without it.

Comment: Anaconda is especially brain-dead when it comes to generating the hosts file at install. It always puts the hostname on 127.0.0.1. Applications like Oracle don't like this.