# Unable to Create Rule in IPTables to Open Port 80

Tags: centos, iptables

I'm trying to open port 80 in iptables but am running into a couple issues. I am running CentOS 5.7.

First I tried to run this command:

```
iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

But I received an error saying:

```
iptables: command not found
```

So I then ran the same command but with sbin added:

```
/sbin/iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Now I receive this error:

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name
```

Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided.

Comment: what does your `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file look like ?

Comment: Do you already have iptables rules set?  What do you see if you do an `iptables -n --list`?

Comment: Your initial problem is caused because `/sbin` is not in your path - and this can often happen if you are not `root` or if you `sudo root` without changing the `PATH` variable to include `/sbin` (and `/usr/sbin`).

Comment: What makes you think a chain named "RH-Firewall-1-INPUT" should exist? What does the output of `iptables -L` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ran `service iptables stop` as someone suggested in the other Question you posted, then all iptables rules have been flushed, and there is no "RH-Firewall-1-INPUT" chain.

Assuming you're using the default firewall, do `service iptables start`.  Run `iptables -n --list` as Zoredache suggests to verify that a chain named "RH-Firewall-1-INPUT" exists.  If so, then the command you've shown should work.  Run `service iptables save` afterwards to save it to the config file, so it will be there on the next reboot.

If there is no "RH-Firewall-1-INPUT" chain, the edit your question to show the results of the `iptables -n --list`, and we can proceed from there.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to do, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

run "iptables -nvL", see what the correct name of your chains are then run something like this to append the rule to the chain:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Here's a great link that I used to learn IPtables: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Hope this helps

Comment: This is a great site, going to read through it carefully. Thanks for your help.