# Apache2 on Centos

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, socket

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Configuring Apache on CentOS 5.7](https://serverfault.com/questions/360899/configuring-apache-on-centos-5-7)

I've purcheased a vps and installed apache2. As developer i've been doing this hundreds of times with no problem. Now I'm facing this:
netstat -nao
outputs apache2 is listening on :::80 but not on 0.0.0.0:80

I get NO errors at all.
Logs have no errors too.

Ideas? Links? Blog posts? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem your facing.

Comment: I would expect from netstat 0.0.0.0:80 listening socket... but I only get :::80. So when trying to browse mywebsite.com... it obviously refuses connection

Comment: Did you open port 80 in your firewall ?

Comment: Yes. but didn't work. Anyway I think I should see 0.0.0.0:80 listening even if a firewall is blocking it... Am i wrong?

Comment: My centos system says the same and works as expected, your problem isn't one of binding.

Comment: uhmmm ok. 1 problem less

Comment: So why ssh service is showing :::22 and 0.0.0.0:22 ?

Comment: What do you mean by, "installed apache2"?  CentOS ships with Apache 2, but it's named "httpd" as the package.  Did you install apache2 separately?  Is it conflicting with the pre-installed httpd package?

Comment: Ok the problem was iptables. I did insert a rule to allow incoming requests on port 80 but "-A" is for Append... and the rule never had the chance to be matched. So using "-I" for insert solved the problem.

iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 0):

Binding to `:::80` means that it is listening to both IPv4 *and* IPv6 connections; this is not causing your problem.