# Configure domain name in CentOS

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, configuration, centos5, domain-name

How do I configure domain names in Cent OS?

I am actually connecting to the servers via SSH remote terminal and I also have root credentials. Does configuring the `/etc/sysconfig/network` and `/etc/hosts` suffice? Would be great to have some steps or configuration guides..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Four things to do:

- Add the hostname entry to `/etc/hosts`. Use the [format detailed here](https://serverfault.com/questions/331936/setting-the-hostname-fqdn-or-short-name/331942#331942).
- If your hostname is "your_hostname", type `hostname your_hostname` at a command prompt to make the change effective.
- Define the hostname in `/etc/sysconfig/network` to make this setting persist across reboots.
- Reboot the system or restart services that depend on hostname (cups, syslog, apache, sendmail, etc.)

Answer (score 9):

If by domain name you mean domain suffix, then `/etc/resolv.conf` is where the domain goes. Just add a line `domain yourdomain.com`

Then to set your server's hostname, there's only one good place for it, and it's `/etc/sysconfig/network`. Add a line `HOSTNAME=yourhostname`, and don't put the domain suffix in the hostname, as it will take it from `/etc/resolv.conf`.

You do not need to add anything (and shouldn't) in `/etc/hosts` to define your hostname. This is the wrong way to do it.

To test your setup, use the `hostname` command:

- Use `hostname -s` to get the short name (should reflect what you have in `/etc/sysconfig/network`
- Use the `hostname -d` command to test your domain (should reflect what you have in `/etc/resolv.conf`)
- To test it all together, you can use `hostname -f` or `hostname -A` for the very long version.

Comment: In CentOS 7 `HOSTNAME` in `/etc/sysconfig/network` no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it now is `hostnamectl hostname.domainname`

Comment: `hostnamectrl set-hostname <hostname>` you should not use the FQDN here