# Can't access server running CentOS 6.3 in vmware

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6

I just installed CentOS on a vmware machine that uses a bridged connection, installed apache, php and mysql, but when I run `service httpd start` I get a warning(?):

```
Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain for ServerName
```

I can connect to the server using putty, so I really have no idea why it won't load in the browser.

**EDIT:**

Httpd starts successfully, return **[ OK ]**. Running `netstat -tuplen | grep :80` yields:

```
tcp   0   0 :::80     :::*     LISTEN    0     40392   15894/httpd
```

I am able to connect with putty to 192.168.0.113, but browser says `can't connect to 192.168.0.113`

Comment: Does `httpd` finish starting successfully after that?  Does it end up listening on the correct ports?  What address are you using to access the system, and what error do you get in your browser?

Comment: updated question

Comment: [You should fix your `/etc/hosts` file](http://serverfault.com/questions/331936/setting-the-hostname-fqdn-or-short-name/331942#331942) to reflect the host's name and fully-qualified domain name regardless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll hazard a guess that you have default rules blocking port 80 in `iptables`.

Verify with `iptables -L` - there probably isn't a rule allowing the port 80 traffic.

Use `iptables -I INPUT -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` to allow the traffic, and `service iptables save` to make the change persistent.

Comment: Perfect! Used -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT in /etc/sysconfig/iptables and now it's all good.