# CentOS 5.8 why does my /etc/hosts file mess up after a reboot?

Tags: linux, centos, centos5, hosts, hosts-file

I'm running CentOS 5.8 (it's the Citrix XVA appliance provided on the website) but having an issue where every time I restart the server, the /etc/hosts file loses the IP address of the server...for instance, the way the host file should looks is like so:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost.localdomain localhost
10.0.0.50     localhost.localdomain citrix-ls
```

But instead, after a reboot, it looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost.localdomain localhost
              localhost.localdomain citrix-ls
```

Anyone have any idea why this would be happening?  I'm thinking of just writing a script to replace the /etc/hosts file at each boot.

Any assistance would be appreciated--thanks!

-slashp

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, this is an incorrect setup. You should consider making your hosts file reflect the following, where "youdomain.name" is your local network's [fully-qualified domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) (FQDN):

```
127.0.0.1     localhost.localdomain localhost
10.0.0.50     citrix-ls.yourdomain.name citrix-ls
```

Also see:
[Setting the hostname: FQDN or short name?](https://serverfault.com/questions/331936/setting-the-hostname-fqdn-or-short-name/331942#331942)

Comment: Ok that's fine, I can fix that when I come to it.  For now, any ideas why the hosts file would be clearing out the IP address on each reboot?

Comment: "localhost.localdomain" is repeated. The file is read top-to-bottom. You may have a dynamic DNS or DHCP arrangement at the location. You may not have the hostname defined in `/etc/sysconfig/network`... There could be a few reasons.

Comment: Gotcha.  I have a static IP set in my /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-seth0 and my hostname set in /etc/sysconfig/network as well as /etc/sysctl.conf.  Tried manually creating an A record on my DNS server but still no dice.

Comment: Change your `/etc/hosts` file as I specified in the original answer. That was meant to be the fix.

Comment: I did, the IP still blanks out after every reboot.  Quite odd actually.  See my ifcfg-seth0 & /etc/hosts file configuration as well if it's helpful: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=UGmEe4ft

Comment: Figured it out..turns out a Citrix script was writing to the /etc/hosts file and not able to pick up on the proper IP..instead of trying to figure out why, I just commented out the line.  Thanks anyway for the help :)!

Comment: Well, damn... that works.