# How to configure RHEL so users can access an app GUI remotely

Tags: ssh, redhat, remote-access, graphical-user-interface, x11

I have an application installed in my RHEL6 box that has a GUI (AppGui.sh). My problem is that a few non-tech users would like to access this GUI remotely. I've tried several guides over the internet but I still cant make it work.

I tried:
-Installing X Window System
-Enabling FORWARDX11=yes in my sshd_config
-Exporting $DISPLAY variable
-Connecting through ssh -X user@host (simply stays there)

How can I setup my box from scratch to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this the easy way with [NoMachine (NX)](http://www.nomachine.com/download.php). It's basically compressed X11 over SSH. So all you'll need on the remote side is a client (Mac, Windows, Linux) and to install a server piece on the RHEL6 box you're trying to connect to.

Anything else if going to be a bit slow (raw X11 forwarding), choppy (VNC) or a pain to setup (what you're going through now).

Comment: Ok will try this now and Ill let you know.

Comment: Ugh... its giving me errors at the start session... `Oct  5 09:59:06 isvahlrtk01 NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[53330]: ERROR: (exception id 5B3926AB) NX> 596 ERROR: execution of last command failed
Oct  5 09:59:06 isvahlrtk01 NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[53330]: ERROR: (exception id 5B3926AB) NX> 596 last command: /usr/bin/xauth -v -f /home/tkadmin/.nx/C-isvahlrtk01-1004-A4C27A6B9F9A3BA43DECD3703AF73C9B/authority source /home/tkadmin/.nx/C-isvahlrtk01-1004-A4C27A6B9F9A3BA43DECD3703AF73C9B/scripts/authority`

Comment: Ok found the solution for that problem. You need to add your hostname to `/etc/hosts` like this "127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain localhost my_simple_hostname_here"

now to deal with another error. Will keep you posted.

Comment: @Rhyuk Your `/etc/hosts` should follow [these guidelines](http://serverfault.com/questions/331936/setting-the-hostname-fqdn-or-short-name/331942#331942).

Comment: Good News! Got it working! Bad news, theres a known bug with gnome desktop. Only loads background and the CTRL+ALT+R workaround doesnt work for me :/

Comment: Gnome doesn't load and KDE wont install because of a mysql-lib dependency. Ugh...

Comment: Did you run a `yum groupinstall "KDE Desktop"`?

Comment: Fixed the dependency hell I had. Its working fine now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me is to use MobaXterm: you just have to

- Download it here: http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html
- Click on the "new session" button and type your RHEL server name or IP address
- Start the session and run your GUI app.

You have nothing else to do: MobaXterm automatically starts an X11 server and uses X11-Forwarding to display your remote GUI app. This is done without any need for further configuration, so it is very easy.