# Linux - if I change the hostname, which services need to be restarted?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, redhat, hostname

I'm making some system hostname changes across a few environments and this got me thinking...

When I change a server's hostname (live), what needs to be modified and which system services require a restart?
Assume this is done online without a reboot.

I encounter a lot of systems built by other people where hostname changes are made in-flight, but the changes either do not persist across a reboot, or I notice that `/var/log/messages` are stamped with a different hostname.

I regularly follow:

- Run `hostname <new-short-hostname>`
- Modify `/etc/hosts` [according to these guidelines](https://serverfault.com/questions/331936/setting-the-hostname-fqdn-or-short-name/331942#331942).
- Modify `/etc/sysconfig/network`

On the daemon side...

- sendmail/postfix (matching hostname is required)
- cups (print daemon may stop with bad hostname)
- syslog/rsyslog (hostname is logged along with system messages)
- httpd (proper hostname is required)

What else requires attention?

Comment: On which distribution?

Comment: Red Hat derivatives.

Comment: Avidly awaiting the responses.

Comment: Why do you have a hostname set in your httpd(apache) config?  Other then hosting a vhost for the systems hostname, it shouldn't be required anywhere.

Comment: @Zoredache Because of "httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends on the distribution. From your post, it looks very much like you are using either RHEL or CentOS. That's what I'll assume in my answer.

A lot of services look at the server's hostname, so it is very hard to generally give a complete overview of which services you need to restart. However, be aware of the following:

- Some Postfix installs have the hostname hardcoded in config as well.
- Same goes for Apache
- If you use NFS, you need to care for that
- On RHEL HA clusters you need to care for the cluster configuration

Usually, I also issue `hostname new.host.name` to set the hostname without rebooting.

Also, I grep through `/etc` and subdirs (config files) to find anywhere the server hostname has been set. Same goes for configuration files of custom compiled software.

Another thing to be aware of is external dependencies. In the environments I usually work with, things like Monitoring, Backup and Configuration Management are also dependant on the hostname of the server, and a lot of stuff will break if this is not taken into consideration.

Comment: +1 on the `hostname` command. I did not think about the config files in `/etc`. Any other examples?

Comment: I've been pondering about this question. I can't come to think of more things, but I will have it in mind next time I have to change one, and if I come across something that is not mentioned here, count on me updating my answer :)