# Should I change the hostnames?? Scientific Linux VirtualBoxes?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, virtualbox

Should I change the hostnames?? Scientific Linux VirtualBoxes?.

I have a number of Scientific Linux VirtualBoxes all running on my computer.. Some of them are Scientific Linux some are CentOS... The issue is that I keep all of them running and I ssh into to do work... I don't use the GUI to much.  the issue is the from the term it looks like:

**[jjoes@localhost ~]$**

in all my windows and sometimes I can't tell which VM I am working in..  Can someone please tell me the best way to work around this?  should I change the hostnames?? if so are the services going to break?? whats the best and fasters why to do this so I can tell from the command line which VM I am in?

Comment: If you want to change the name, then change the name.  If the name change would break something simply change your `PS1` prompt if you are using bash.  Since they are VMs you could just make a snapshot, and test.  We have no idea what will break since you have told us nothing about your systems.  But there are lots of things that could break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should change the host names if these are persistent virtual machines...

[Here are the steps](https://serverfault.com/questions/435557/linux-if-i-change-the-hostname-which-services-need-to-be-restarted) needed to change a hostname cleanly on a RHEL/CentOS/SL server.

- Run hostname
- Modify /etc/hosts according to [these guidelines](https://serverfault.com/questions/331936/setting-the-hostname-fqdn-or-short-name/331942#331942).
- Modify /etc/sysconfig/network to made the change permanent and survive reboots.