# linux server still recognizes the old domain after changing it to new one

Tags: linux, redhat, log-files

I have some Linux servers (`RHEL` 6.3 and 5.4) under one domain (MS Windows server 2008R2) and every thing was working fine, but we decided to change the domain from `olddomain.com` to `newdomain.com`, now the new domain under (Windows server 2012), I changed the domain from the old one to the new one in all Linux servers.

The result of `$dnsdomainname` command is `newdomain.com` on all Linux servers. when I ping any Linux server from it give me `Lin_name.newdomain.com` but the problem I am facing now the log inside log rotate and forward still recognize the old domain. it give me like the following:

```
Nov 19 10.00.09 Lin_name.olddomain.com Lin_name [message like someone logged in or out start proccess ..etc]
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you reboot or restart any of the Linux system services? If not, you'll need to...

Also see: [Linux - if I change the hostname, which services need to be restarted?](https://serverfault.com/questions/435557/linux-if-i-change-the-hostname-which-services-need-to-be-restarted)

Comment: Thanks, But I did that before asking the question. and if you ping the server it give you the new domain name but in the log it give you the old one

Comment: Did you restart the syslog or rsyslog services?

Comment: yes, I restarted the services

Comment: Did you rename the server? Check `/etc/sysconfig/network`

Comment: yes the server name under the new domain, the thing I don't understand if you ping the server using ping Lin_name it give you Lin_name.newdomain.com , but the log still write Lin_name.olddomain.com

Comment: For some reason, syslog isn't recognizing that the hostname has changed yet.  The fact that `ping` shows the correct domain name just means that name resolution is working, nothing more.  The fact that `dnsdomainname` shows the right information, but syslog doesn't makes me think that syslog (or rsyslog, or syslog-ng, or whatever logger your systems are using) didn't restart properly after the name change.