# apache won't start httpd service start centos 6.3

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, centos6

I've installed httpd in CentOS 6.3

```
yum install httpd
```

After successfully installing it, I tried to start it

```
service httpd start
```

Nothing happend. I opened the browser and typed my IP address but could not connect.

Update:

Now I've reinstalled httpd

when i run

```
service httpd start
```

message displayed

```
Starting httpd: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Comment: Your Apache logs can be found in `/var/log/httpd`.  What does the error log say?

Comment: Little bit confusing, you say it won't start then you say you a 404, a 404 would suggest that it is running. Do you see the httpd process when you do a "ps aux"? If not then what does the error log show (/var/log/httpd/error.log)?

Comment: i'm sorry Unable to connect message is displayed in mozilla lol

Comment: there is no error.log file

Comment: Ah might be error_log, should be an error log /var/log/httpd folder. If not try running "httpd" in a terminal and it should give an output in the terminal

Comment: service httpd start
Starting httpd: /usr/sbin/httpd: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0: file too short

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

```
yum update
```

then removed httpd

```
yum erase httpd
```

then installed it again

```
yum install httpd
```

and typed

```
service httpd start
```

Now it works!

Answer (score 4):

There could be few issues over here.

1. Selinux -selinux is enabled in your machine, and that is preventing from starting the Apache. You can try disabling selinux and try restarting the httpd. You can do that by this command `setenforce 0`
2. You are not running this command with root privileges. To do that, use sudo and execute the command like this `$ sudo service httpd start`
3. Also, there might be something already running on port 80. To check that use this command `netstat -npl | grep 80`
   If this command is showing something then that means some other application is running on that port.

One last thing you can try is that, you have already http running, and the connection is refused may be because of some firewall or something else.

To check the same, use command with `restart` and simply with `start`.

So, give this command `$ sudo service httpd restart`

If this command doesn't give any error this time, which you are seeing normally, that means that httpd is running but the connection refused is may be because of something else.

Comment: I've tried all what you said but the same error service httpd start
Starting httpd: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]

Comment: Can you tell me what do you see in the error logs

Comment: setenforce 0 - Worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `/etc/hosts` file is configured with a fully-qualified domain name and the server's IP address, [as per this suggestion](https://serverfault.com/questions/331936/setting-the-hostname-fqdn-or-short-name/331942#331942).

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

172.16.100.13   Rizzo.ifp.com rizzo
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

172.16.100.13   Rizzo.ifp.com rizzo

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue with libaprutil, I believe it is provided by the apr package on CentOS 6.3

```
yum reinstall apr-util
```

If that fails then try

```
yum provides libaprutil-1.so.0
```

Which will give you correct package to install/reinstall

Comment: Starting httpd: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs

Comment: That would suggest it is running or something else is listen is on the  port httpd is wanting to use (TCP 80 by default) You can see what is running on port 80 by using the command "netstat -tpln"

Answer (score 0):

Same error.

I found in my ssl_error_log this string:

```
No such file or directory: could not open transfer log file /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_request_log.
```

At /etc/httpd/ was no directory /logs, but strange file '!logs'. I removed it, created 'logs' directory, restart httpd... and it started.

May be it be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

There might be something running on port 80. You can check it by

```
fuser -n tcp 80
```

or use

```
ss -plnt sport eq :80
```

Kill the offending process and you are done.