# What if I follow Oracle Instructions for hostname

Tags: redhat, oracle, hostname, hosts-file

Oracle Docs requiring Hostname to be FQDN. What do you think? Not really what I want to do but... should I?

### Verifying Host Names

Use the following to verify host name settings:
For Oracle Linux 4 and 5, and Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS/ES 4 and 5:

1. Verify that the /etc/hosts file is formatted as follows:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
   [ip_address] [node_name].[domain_name] [node_name]
   ```
2. Verify that the /etc/sysconfig/network file is formatted as follows:

   ```
   HOSTNAME=[node_name].[domain_name]
   ```

Comment: Depends on the application but there is no definitive right or wrong. Some software expects `hostname` to resolve to FQDN, however, there's a `-f` flag for it... I prefer the shortname, personally. (Sometimes that is long enough to be a nuisance at a narrow terminal.)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle is very particular about how they think systems should be managed, and some of their recommendations (specifically 1:1 memory to swap ratios, still recommended as of at least a year ago) make one raise an eyebrow.

Ultimately, do what best serves the environment and the applications involved. Unfortunately, sometimes what best serves the environment is "do what it takes to have Oracle willing to work with this under our support contract".

Answer (score 0):

Go with the [short name](https://serverfault.com/questions/331936/setting-the-hostname-fqdn-or-short-name) unless your application specifically requests/requires the longer [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) as a hostname. Oracle may be a case of the latter.