# MCollective metadata refresh returns: Host name lookup failure

Tags: centos, puppet, mcollective

With puppet installed, the command `/opt/puppet/sbin/refresh-mcollective-metadata` is run every 15 minutes. It loggs `hostname: Host name lookup failure` when it runs.

`hostname`, `hostname -i`, and `hostname -f` all return `hostname: Host name lookup failure`

Answer (score 0):

This can occur because the hostname is not set in CentOS.

Run the command `hostname machine.example.com` to set the hostname on the machine then MCollective and all the above-mentioned hostname commands will return the correct values.

Note: it's probably worth looking at the comments on this solution.

Comment: Setting the hostname to an FQDN is quite a crude workaround. Generally it should be an unqualified name like `machine` in your case. Set the FQDN using `/etc/hosts` - it should be the first entry on the first line that contains the unqualified name as an alias, e.g. `127.0.0.1 machine.example.com machine localhost`

Comment: @FelixFrank thanks for the comment. I did some research based on what you said and found these two relevant resources: 

http://jblevins.org/log/hostname

http://serverfault.com/questions/331936/setting-the-hostname-fqdn-or-short-name

Comment: // , Is the `hostname` command the "canonical" or usual way to set a machine's host name in Linux?

Comment: // , Like Jasmine Longes commented on http://serverfault.com/a/331942/282446, shouldn't /etc/sysconfig/network contain lines like: NETWORKING=yes, NETWORKING_IPV6=no, HOSTNAME=example.com, NISDOMAIN=example ?