# 'Please configure a fully qualified domain name' Error

Tags: centos, email, centos6.5, email-server

I am running an nginx website on a virtual host and I am trying to set up iRedMail, but this is the error I get when running `bash iRedMail.sh`.

> < ERROR > Please configure a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) in
>   /etc/hosts before we go further.

---

**`etc/sysconfig/network` file**

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=mail.website1.com
```

---

**`etc/hosts` file** (xxx.xx.xxx.xxx is my real server ip address)

```
127.0.0.1   mail.website1.com mail localhost
::1         localhost

xxx.xx.xxx.xxx website1.com
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx website2.com
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**Edit: Still coming up with this error.**

> < ERROR > Please configure a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) in
>   /etc/hosts before we go further.
>
> Example:
>
> 127.0.0.1   mail.iredmail.org mail localhost

This is my new config file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

xxx.xx.xxx.xxx website1.com
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx mail.website1.com mail
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx website2.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `/etc/hosts` file should have a separate line defining the system's IP and fully-qualified domain name and the short name on the same line. Remove the "mail.website1.com" and "mail" from the line with `127.0.0.1`.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

10.2.0.6                mail.website1.com mail
```

Make this change and attempt again.

Also see: [Setting the hostname: FQDN or short name?](https://serverfault.com/questions/331936/setting-the-hostname-fqdn-or-short-name/331942#331942)

Comment: Okay, I will do that. I also noticed that nowhere is `website1.com` listed on its own. Won't that cause any issues?

Comment: What you have for website1.com and website2.com is fine. I was just trying to get you past your mail configuration

Comment: Hello, I still get the error as before, and I have edited my post. I read the link you attached - and are you suggesting I change the `HOSTNAME` to something else and replace all `localdomain`'s with the hostname?

Comment: The HOSTNAME variable should probably just be "mail". You'd need to restart the network service; `service network restart` following that. You may also just reboot. Either way. Don't touch any of the localhost/localdomain entries.