# CentOS takes 10 seconds to start anything

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, sendmail, proftpd

I've got CentOS 6 with Apache, Sendmail and Proftpd installed. When I try to start anything on it, ***I mean anything***, it takes 10 seconds.

Sendmail? It takes 10 seconds to send something through PHP's mail().

Proftpd? It takes 10 seconds to get past the "waiting welcome message" part.

SSH? It takes 10 seconds for the server to allow me to input the password, and extra 10 seconds to log me in.

All these issues happen during the ***first load*** of each, if I send an e-mail through mail(), it takes 10 seconds to send it, but the second time I do it, it takes almost instantly. Same for Proftpd.

What is going on?

Comment: strace the startup process. Where does it hang?

Answer (score 5):

Check your DNS resolver situation and `/etc/hosts` configuration.

You want a local hostname defined and the hosts file to be [properly configured](https://serverfault.com/questions/331936/setting-the-hostname-fqdn-or-short-name). And definitely make sure your DNS servers are reachable.