# Getting the "fully qualified canonical domain name" in Linux server

Tags: linux, domain-name

I'm following a guide on setting up SSO for SAP HANA. Part of the requirements are that I find the "fully qualified canonical domain name" of the HANA server I've created. I have access to the server via the command line. Is running the `hostname` command while logged in to the server (logged invia SSH) all I need to do to determine the FQCDN?

Comment: Did it _not_ give you the FQDN?!

Comment: @MichaelHampton I want to confirm that the FQDN is what's returned by the `hostname` command, and also if the reference to 'canonical' makes any difference.

Comment: It is if the system was set up correctly. And 'canonical' is meaningless here. But there's no _automated_ way to tell if the hostname is correct. You will have to inspect it. [Here](https://serverfault.com/q/331936/126632) is a sample of the hell people have gone through _trying_ to automate this. But you can tell at a glance that, e.g. `sap.timhortons.ca` is a FQDN, because you aren't a computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hostname -f` (or --fqdn or --long) should return the fully qualified domain name.