# Is there a term for Second Level Domain and Top Level Domain

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, domain-name

If I observe the domain:

http://www.google.com/

`http` is the protocal

`www` is a subdomain

`google` is the second level domain

`com` is the top level domain

Is there a specific term that would describe `google.com`?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/222095/what-is-the-canonical-name-for-domain-names-with-extra-parts

Comment: www. is not a subdomain if it is a host (*).  Also any domain that is part of a larger domain in the tree is a subdomain.  google is a subdomain of .com

Comment: * it could be argued that it is both a hostname and subdomain. But definately A subdomain rather than THE subdomain

Answer (score 3):

You've already answered your own question. `google.com` would commonly be referred to as a second-level domain name.

Comment: From wikipedia for second level domain: "in example.com, example is the second-level domain of the .com TLD."

Comment: @K2xL right, I think you're reading the wikipedia article a little too literally. The `google` portion can be called a second-level domain, I suppose, but it's useless without knowing the TLD. I've never heard anyone refer to a second-level domain and *only* mean the piece to the left of the TLD.

Answer (score 0):

"Naked domain". Also, in DNS terms - "zone apex"

Also, "second level domain". You wrongly assume that "example" part in "example.com" may be called second-level domain. The whole "example.com" is a domain, and it is a *second-level* domain."example" would be second label in the domain name. "com" is a first (rightmost) label.

Answer (score -5):

Parent Domain which is the combination of the Second Level Domain and the Top level domain

Comment: Wouldn't www.google.com be a FQDN?

Comment: Thanks, update, my understanding was that google.com would be classed as an FQDN and a little research confirmed that, although with comments and proper research I was wrong